# Как сделать пересылку рандом видео из канала в телеграм боте aiogramv

Tags: telegram, aiogram, бот

Шапка. Как заменить на пересылку, а не на отправку из папки как тут:

```
dp.message_handler(text=["Фото ", "Видео "])
async def photo_or_video_(message: types.Message):
    update_status_distribution(user_id=message.from_user.id, value="active")
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user = get_users(user_id=user_id)

    if user[0][5] is not None:
        subTimeout = datetime.datetime.strptime(user[0][5], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

    if (user[0][4]) and (
        (user[0][5] is None)
        or (subTimeout + datetime.timedelta(days=30) < datetime.datetime.now())
    ):
        update_user(user_id=user_id, index="sub_timeout", value=datetime.datetime.now())
        subTimeout = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            get_users(user_id=user_id)[0][5], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
        )

    if (message.text == "Фото ") and (
        (
            user[0][4]
            and (subTimeout + datetime.timedelta(days=30) > datetime.datetime.now())
        )
        or (user[0][1] >= 1)
    ):
        files_ = ["photos", os.listdir("photos")]
    elif (message.text == "Видео ") and (
        (
            user[0][4]
            and (subTimeout + datetime.timedelta(days=30) > datetime.datetime.now())
        )
        or (user[0][1] >= 2)
    ):
        files_ = ["videos", os.listdir("videos")]
    else:
        return await message.answer(
            "У вас недостаточно средств", reply_markup=no_balance()
        )

    if files_[1]:
        with open(f"{files_[0]}/{random.choice(files_[1])}", "rb") as file:
            if not (
                user[0][4]
                and (subTimeout + datetime.timedelta(days=30) > datetime.datetime.now())
            ):
                if files_[0] == "photos":
                    update_user(user_id=user_id, index="balance", value=user[0][1] - 1)
                elif files_[0] == "videos":
                    update_user(user_id=user_id, index="balance", value=user[0][1] - 2)
            if files_[0] == "photos":
                return await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, file)
            elif files_[0] == "videos":
                return await bot.send_video(message.from_user.id, file)
    else:
        return await message.answer(playError, reply_markup=play_keyboard())
```